# Having trouble with resizing the cell in collection view in a chat application

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, resize, constraints

I am creating a little chat message application. For that purpose I am using a collection view. I found a lot of code and managed to bring it together to make it work. However now I try to add some additional labels to the custom cell for the time and - in group chats - the username. But it seems like I cannot add any labels into the bubble view. The timeLabel is underneath the bubble view, although I set the constraints in a way the timetable should be inside the bubble view underneath the textView.

Here is the code:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addSubview(bubbleView)
    addSubview(textView)
    addSubview(profileImageView)
    addSubview(timeView)
    addSubview(usernameView)



    //x,y,w,h
    profileImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    // profileImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true
    profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true
    profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bubbleView.topAnchor).isActive = true

    //x,y,w,h

    bubbleViewRightAnchor = bubbleView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -8)
    bubbleViewRightAnchor?.isActive = true
    bubbleViewLeftAnchor = bubbleView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 8)
    // bubbleViewLeftAnchor?.isActive = false
    bubbleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    bubbleWidthAnchor = bubbleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
    bubbleWidthAnchor?.isActive = true
    bubbleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    //ios 9 constraints
    //x,y,w,h
   //  textView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    textView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bubbleView.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    textView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bubbleView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    // textView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: timeView.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true

    timeView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    //timeView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bubbleView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    timeView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    timeWidthAnchor = timeView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
    timeWidthAnchor?.isActive = true

  /*  usernameView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    usernameView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    nameWidthAnchor =  usernameView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
    nameWidthAnchor?.isActive = true
    usernameView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20)
    nameHeightAnchor?.isActive = true */
}
```

I think the problem is the sizeForItemAt method in the collection view. But to be honest I have no idea how to change that method so that it still works with the textview as it does at the moment.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    var height: CGFloat = 80
    let text: String?
    //get estimated height somehow????
    if messages[indexPath.item].text != nil {
        text = messages[indexPath.item].text
        height = estimateFrameForText(text!).height + 20
    }

    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}

fileprivate func estimateFrameForText(_ text: String) -> CGRect {
    let size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 1000)
    let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
    return NSString(string: text).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)], context: nil)
}
```

[image: sample chat]

Comment: Understand code that you pasted together.

Comment: This is an attempt of understanding it better. As I said it is just the estimated height function, that is not totally clear to me. I understand why you have to do it and as a result I know what it is doing. But I failed when trying to change the  output of this function.

Answer (score 0):

## Try the following:

1. In the `UICollectionViewCell` subclass, add subviews to `contentView` and not to the cell directly
2. In the cell, ensure that the constraints of the subviews tie to the `contentView`
3. If you are using UICollectionViewFlowLayout, then set the `itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize`
4. If you are using UICollectionViewFlowLayout, then set the `estimatedItemSize` to an approximate size

Comment: Hey thanks, I tried it, but this error has shown up: 'UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: -setFrame: with CGRectNull is undefined.'

Comment: and what is the difference between point 3 and 4? I've just used point 3 in the override method sizeforitemAt and returned itemSize

Comment: I finally understand all points, but id didn't solve the problem. The timeView is still beneath the bubble view, which gets me really frustrated. And suddenly there are multiple cells in one line cutting each other.

Comment: Are you using a flow layout ? Reading the UICollectionView documentation would help